# Animate opacity based on view's position in scrollview

Tags: react-native

I'm using the [react-native-swiper](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper) component to allow the user to swipe horizontally between different listviews. I would like to animate the opacity of these listviews so they are at full opacity when centered on the screen and fade out when swiped left or right. I have tried to use the onScroll event of the parent scrollview (the swiper component) and then using RCTUIManager on the listview components to get their current position on the screen:

```
var handle = React.findNodeHandle(this.refs['list']);
RCTUIManager.measure(handle, (x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY)
```

But the resulting animation is really really choppy and i'm guessing that is because it uses the onScroll event to update the opacity value.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you find a performant solution? I'd like to do something similar using either ScrollView or ListView to animate the opacity of items entering/leaving the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

probably not relevant anymore since this is an old question but now you can use `useNativeDriver: true` on your scrollView and animate the opacity based on the scroll event with good performance.

[this blog post explains it really well](https://hackernoon.com/react-native-performance-an-updated-example-6516bfde9c5c)

Answer (score -2):

If you use the facebook built Navigator component rather than swiper you can configure Scene Configs that fade in and out and you expect.

Not sure how well gestures are supported but the Navigator though.

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html

Please avoid using the NavigatorIOS because it's totally unsupported by facebook and seems to have lots of bugs!